# Does " @import 'bourbon/bourbon' " work as effectively as importing individual mixins?

Tags: css, sass, mixins, bourbon

Does " @import 'bourbon/bourbon' " work as effectively as importing individual mixins from each of bourbons folders as needed?  For example: if I import only the css3 mixins (@import 'bourbon/css3') I need from bourbon, rather than the whole '@import bourbon/bourbon' will this perform better? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using it *just* for CSS3 mixins, consider using something like [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) instead, as it provides greater flexibility regarding which prefixes to apply.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run any benchmarks, but I would imagine that the difference in compiling performance would be minimal, if any. The main difference would be in the size of the output - importing CSS that you don't need will simply generate a larger file for the user to download. So if you don't need the full library, then just import the parts your app needs and save your users some bandwidth.

Comment: It's all functions, variables and mixins, so by itself Bourbon doesn't actually add any additional CSS to output. As you point out, there may be some difference in compiling, but IMHO it's minimal and greatly outweighed by the convenience factor.

Comment: That's true, I had forgotten that about bourbon. So unless you're noticing some slowdown in your asset compile time it's probably nothing to trouble with.